# Android GPS location vs other GPS devices

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, geocoding

Hey I am beginning to look into making an android app. Trying to use the phonegap right now.

I was just wondering about the geolocation service. It seems the address is always a few block off of my actual location. Even if I have it set to enable hight accuracy. How come GPS people have in their cars know down to the location on the block they are on. Is there a way to get an accuracy like this with android? Or is it easier to get better data when moving?

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with Android itself? It's just as likely to be the hardware - after all, it gathers the positional data and any software which uses it can only be as good as the hardware accuracy. Just for the record, Google Maps on my Android phone using GPS and 3G (for map data) currently shows the location arrow directly on the roof of my house above the room I'm sitting in. I'd say maybe 2-3 metres accuracy. There are a lot of factors involved with GPS and pretty much all of them are to do with hardware and visibility of satellites.

Comment: Cool thanks. And I only asked android as that is what I am developing on. Mine is an older-ish model.

Comment: I usually find when I sometimes get inaccurate data for my location, moving on a short distance or just waiting for better satellite visibility will help things. Being surrounded by tall buildings, for example, won't help things and in some ways your question about car GPS systems getting better data when moving is partly correct. Particularly on an open road with good radio reception.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have GPS enabled? Android phones can get location based on network (GPRS, EDGE, 3G, UMTS, Wifi, etc) or GPS. If you have GPS enabled you'll get better location than only network, which gives you a range, a circle where you are in.